# How can I add a new document to Content Server with Category Attribute value (BuilingId )using the postman

Tags: rest, api, postman, opentext, livelink

How can I add a new document to Content Server with Category Attribute value  (BuilingId )using the postman[image]

Comment: what baseurl you have used?

Comment: @rupaliaggarwal What do you mean by base url

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do too much at once. 
First add the file
then apply the category, then add the buildingID to the category.
See this [thread on Appworks Site](https://developer.opentext.com/webaccess/#url=%2Fawd%2Fforums%2Fquestions%2F6673111%2Frest%2Bapi%2Bcategories), top post explains that in detail.

Then once you are ready to edit the category...
Use the form id of the input box for BuildingID , for example 
Key: "_1_1_13_1"
Value: "Your Data"

you will find this on the form itself in the html;

```
<textarea class="valueEditable multiline"  ----> id="_1_1_13_1" <----  name="_1_1_13_1" title="BuildingID" rows="5" cols="64" onchange="markDirty();"></textarea>
```

The best thing to figure this out is to use [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) and [Postman Interceptor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo) from the Chrome App Store.

Using these you can see what the form is sending to the server when you normally submit the category info, then work backwards from there.

Comment: Tried by passing buildingid key (1_1_2_1 in my case )  but didn't  work

Comment: @platinums And the category is applied on the root level that is in the parent_node.. not that you can upload the doc and then add the category to it..